# could not convert string to float:

Tags: python

This function didn't convert file into matrix prperly, while I run the code I got error message: 
    returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]

ValueError: could not convert string to float.

```
def fileToMatrix(filename):
        fr = open(filename)
        numberOfLines = len(fr.readlines())
        returnMat = np.zeros((numberOfLines,3))
        classLabelVector = []
        fr = open(filename)
        index = 0 
        for line in fr.readline():
            line = line.strip() #split in the end of the line
            listFromLine = line.split('\t') # split on tab and make list
            returnMat[index,:] = listFromLine[0:3]
            classLabelVector.append(int(listFromLine[-1]))
            index += 1

        return returnMat, classLabelVector



    if __name__ == '__main__':

        filename ="mydata.txt"
        returnMat,classLabelVector=fileToMatrix(filename)
        print(returnMat)
```

and data file looks like:

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWHei.png)

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the error message as text in your question.

Comment: @mkrieger1 done

Comment: does your data contain any lines that have less numbers or lines that are empty (even if it is the last line after all others)?

Comment: no all lines have related data, not empty and nan value

Answer (score 0):

haha... error is in the line:

```
for line in fr.readline():
```

I should have used readlines() function to read all the line of the .txt file